# How to add current time stamp to header in Excel Power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to pull data into excel using the service provider's API. The service provider specifies that the api header should have a timestamp. How can I add a timestamp as a header to a power query in excel?

My query:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://vendorapi/data", [Headers=[#"api-key"="apikey", #"api-req-time"="timestamp"]]))
in
    Source
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
let Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://vendorapi/dat?api_key=83213452fd&api-req-time="&Date.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow()),"yyyy-MM-dd"))
in Source
```

Comment: I should specify in the Headers.

Comment: Excellent. Happy to be of service.